# Audio recording in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms project which has to record the audio and save it localy on the app.

Is there any plugin / api which can be used to achieve this?

Also I would like to know the source of the recorind ie. whether it is being recorded from microphone or is it from handsfree (speaker) without using microphone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no plugin that I know of that does this. you could create a generic service interface called `IRecorder` which has the functionality you need and then implement the `IRecorder` interface in the platform specific projects using called AndroidRecorder etc using the [dependency service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/)

when implementing your platform specific code you can use these samples

- [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/record_audio/)
- [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/record_sound/)
- [Windows 10](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b876a/audio-recorder-in-windows-10-universal-windows-platform/)

Answer (score 8):

There is an open-source plugin for working with audio recorder in Xamarin.Forms :

https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [dependency service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to access platform-specific APIs such as [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/) on iOS or [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) on Android.